# member in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the code (in routes.rb):

```
  resources :products do
    member do
      get :delete #this works
      delete delete: "products#destroy" #this doesn't work
      delete "delete" => "products#destroy" #but this works
    end
  end
```

Why the line `delete delete: "products#destroy"` doesn't work and the line `delete "delete" => "products#destroy"` works?

Rails version 3.2.11

Comment: Why would it work? - that second delete looks spurious to me.

Comment: @gg_s no, this is the new ruby syntax for hashmap.

Comment: Shouldn't `delete:` be `:delete` in the second version?

Comment: I couldn't find notation you are trying to use in documentation nor guides. Resourceful routing is meant to be simple, and use CoC paradigm. Path in your route should be identical to method name in controller.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas no because the first delete is a method, the second delete is a symbol and the string is a value.

Comment: @danilodeveloper so apart from my answer, as seen in the docs. Using member you are not expected to map to a controller#action. Your mapping should be what the action name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work and if you follow the error backtrace is because of the following line in the `mapper.rb` in Rails.

```
def match(path, *rest)
  if rest.empty? && Hash === path
    options  = path
    path, to = options.find { |name, value| name.is_a?(String) }
    options[:to] = to
    options.delete(path)
    paths = [path]
  else
    options = rest.pop || {}
     paths = [path] + rest
  end

  options[:anchor] = true unless options.key?(:anchor)

  if options[:on] && !VALID_ON_OPTIONS.include?(options[:on])
    raise ArgumentError, "Unknown scope #{on.inspect} given to :on"
  end
  paths.each { |_path| decomposed_match(_path, options.dup) }
  self
end
```

This is called by all the methods behind the scenes (e.g `delete`, `post`, `get`, `put`). The line that we are specifically looking for is the one that goes like this:

```
path, to = options.find { |name, value| name.is_a?(String) }
```

Not sure why they are checking against a String but since the name is a symbol and not a `String` but a `Symbol`. That pretty much sends that path as a nil value into `decomposed_match` causing somewhere down the line the reason why you cannot use a symbol in the routes.

**NOTE**

```
resources :products do
  member do
    get :delete #this works
    delete delete: "products#destroy" #this doesn't work
    delete "delete" => "products#destroy" #but this works
  end
end
```

The reason why `get :delete` works is because of the line before the `match` method is called.

Specifically under this method

```
def map_method(method, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options[:via] = method
  args.push(options)
  match(*args, &block)
  self
end
```

the line `args.extract_options!` removes a hash out of the array. You can find this under the file `extract_options.rb` which is an added method to the class `Array`.

Anyhow, since `get :delete` is not a hash but a single parameter it gets mapped to something like this

```
Path: [delete]
Options [{via: "get"}]
```

Now, the other ones get mapped like this take for example `delete delete: "product#destroy"`

```
Path {:delete=>"collaborators#destroy", via: "delete"}
Options []
```

Then it goes back to my original statement as to why Symbols don't work in the routes.

Comment: Not sure if I explained myself well enough. So anyone that reads this have at it on editing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to map delete action to destroy you should use `match`

```
match 'products/:id/delete', controller: :products, action: :destroy, via: :delete
```

but I don't see a reason to do this. In my opinion you should stick with rails default destroy action.

And it doesn't work because in resources you already have controller specified and it used for adding actions with proper http protocols

Comment: Okay, but why the third line works and the second line doesn't work, apparently is same code, one using symbols and other using String.

Comment: Symbols are not the same what Strings are, so there is no reason for them to behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

The new hash syntax is only supported from Ruby version 1.9. Which version of Ruby are you using?